# What is the proper way to cite the usage of an API?

Tags: citations, online-resource

For a grant I am writing, I need to describe how I mined data from social media sites. I collected data from sites such as Twitter using each site's API and a Python wrapper. In writing my methods, I assume that I should mention which APIs I used, or at least that I used an API.

Do I need to provide a citation if I refer to using, say, the Python wrapper for Twitter's API. If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll find any documented correct way to do this. Personally, I would write a sentence saying that I did it, a sentence describing what an API is, and a link to the version-specific API documentation website (i.e., `https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/` for the API Version 3 instead of `https://developers.google.com/youtube/` the general Youtube API help website).

If you're including code in the submission, consider adding the API code in an appendix.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard way, some APIs have a notes sections that have things like citations, and things like that.

Sometimes, the API comes attached to some paper, in which case you should cite the paper.

I've mostly seen people citing the webpage itself if no other resource is available